# Raycast at an offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am trying to make an enemy in my game that can see the light coming from the flashlight of the player. I am doing this by raycasting from the origin of the flashlight towards 5 directions: the middle of the light beam, and the top, bottom, left and right end of the light. Something like this:

[image]

I use the following update function in the flashlight of the player:

```
void Update () {
    float angle = GetComponent<Light>().spotAngle;
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.forward, out hitMiddle)){
        hitMiddlePosition = hitMiddle.transform.position;
    }
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, Quaternion.AngleAxis(-angle, transform.up) * transform.forward, out hitDown)){
        hitDownPosition = hitDown.transform.position;
    }
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle,transform.up) * transform.forward, out hitUp)){
        hitUpPosition = hitUp.transform.position;
    }
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle,transform.right) * transform.forward, out hitRight)){
        hitRightPosition = hitRight.transform.position;
    }
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, Quaternion.AngleAxis (-angle, transform.right) * transform.forward, out hitLeft)){
        hitLeftPosition = hitLeft.transform.position;
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to track the location of each of the hits. However, the locations never seem to correspond to the locations the light beam is hitting. The locations usually are identical in all directions (Vector3(-87.77855, 0, 87.83269))  and do not change when the player is moving. Looking in different directions sometimes changes one of the values.

I tried a lot of different ways of the direction for the raycasts, but I am still not very confident the rays are being cast in the direction I intended.

Any tips?

Many thanks!

Comment: are you confirm that output is omit from all cases? (is every case is running)?
did you try the 11th overload of raycast that takes (Vector3,Vector3,out Raycast, float distance) instead?

Comment: 3- Rotation around axis like ceiling fan is Up axis. Are you confusing or mixing them?
I think if you want rotate in front, you should rotate around Z-Axis instead of Up Vector.
Its all my theoretical question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! The forward direction of the flashlight is the z-direction and it is the only direction I would not like to rotate over. Every case is indeed running, since the values are somtimes updated.
I am not sure whether to add the transform.forward to the multiplication when doing the offsets. However, the middle raycast seems to not be working either, so that is currently my first problem..

Comment: Lets move one by one. Try the overload with distance for middle one like if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.forward, out hitMiddle,100))

Comment: By the way one interesting question I have. If all rays hit to the same body so it will definitely return the same position as you get transform.position in all cases :P

Comment: I tried a distance of both 10 and 100 for the middle raycast, and the values do not change. The middle raycast gives the same value even if it is out of range. I do not quite understand why, because if I check transform.position, it does give the location of the player (which is used for the raycast and is clearly out of range of the location it gives).

Comment: OK, I have done some work for you. see [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x0bb8klqu8ddyh/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-23%20at%202.50.18%20pm.png?dl=0). Observe the direction. It is working fine with if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.forward, out hitMiddle, 100)). Although at distance 10 ray is not colliding to anything

Comment: The distance does not seem to make a difference in my case. I tracked the distance, but even out of range, it returns the value mentioned earlier.. I do not understand how my code is different from yours.
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=523BCFF83B6591ED!166194&authkey=!APpsIbtfCldIuw4&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: Did you observe the direction?

Comment: The flashlight is a child of the player, does that make a difference in direction when using transform.forward? I presumed transform.forward takes global directions, but it probably won't work if it takes a local direction.

Comment: I just did try the same, but that makes no difference. Same result with same transform. You are right. Light will through Ray according to its own transform (local transform). If script attached to the light directly

Comment: A suggestion, attach a dummy child gameobject at position of light but with direction of Player and attach script to it. Carry Light on that script by making it public or any other way you like

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found the problem (see my reply below).

Comment: Did you observe my 4th comment? That is "By the way one interesting question I have. If all rays hit to the same body so it will definitely return the same position as you get transform.position in all cases :P". I told the same :)

Comment: Well, Good to see your problem is solved :)

Comment: Oh, I see now! I didn't quite understand the second sentence and was a little too busy with other things to ask about it. That's my own fault then haha, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, and it was (of course) very trivial.
The problem was that hit.transform.position gave the position of the object that was hit, not the position of the actual intersect location.
Changing this to hit.point resolved the problem. It now works as designed.